How to Decrypt text Enrcypted by Laravel Open SSL in React js?
I want to decrypt text that is encyrypted with open ssl by laravel here is the laravel code
class Encryption
{
    private string $encryptMethod = 'AES-256-CBC';
    private string $key;
    private string $iv;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $mykey = env('MY_ENCRYPTION_KEY');
        $myiv = env('MY_ENCRYPTION_IV');
        $this->key = substr(hash('sha256', $mykey), 0, 32);
        $this->iv = substr(hash('sha256', $myiv), 0, 16);
    }

    public function encrypt(string $value): string
    {
        return openssl_encrypt($value, $this->encryptMethod, $this->key, 0, $this->iv);
    }

    public function decrypt(string $base64Value): string
    {
        return openssl_decrypt($base64Value, $this->encryptMethod, $this->key, 0, $this->iv);
    }
}

I tried many methods in react including with crypto js library but every time i got malformed utf8 can anyone please give me react function to decrypt text provided by open ssl
Thanks
below is my Reactjs Code
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import CryptoJS from 'crypto-js';

const DecryptText = () => {
  const [decryptedText, setDecryptedText] = useState('');
  const encryptedText = 'knztSH5Icp3imQ9UQ4vdaQ=='; // replace with the encrypted text from Laravel

  useEffect(() => {
    const key = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse("com.oneapp.manager");
    const iv = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse("com.oneapp.consumer");

    // Decode the Base64-encoded encryptedText
    const decodedEncryptedText = atob(encryptedText);

    // Convert the decoded string to a WordArray
    const decodedWordArray = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(decodedEncryptedText);

    // Decrypt the WordArray using the key and IV
    const decryptedWordArray = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(decodedWordArray, key, {
      iv: iv,
      padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7,
      mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
    });

    // Convert the decrypted WordArray to a string
    const decryptedText = decryptedWordArray.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);

    setDecryptedText(decryptedText);
  }, [encryptedText]);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Decrypted Text:</h1>
      <p>{decryptedText}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default DecryptText;


Is the test data in the JavaScript code consistent and has it been generated with the PHP code?

The test data is generated with php code

In the first place, both codes differ in the key and IV derivation. For compatibility with the PHP code, in the JavaScript code:

the SHA256 hash of the key material must be generated,
the hash must be hex encoded,
the first 32 bytes of the hex encoded data are to be used as key.

The same applies to the IV, whereby the first 16 bytes are to be applied.
Furthermore, the ciphertext is to be passed to AES.decrypt() as CipherParams object or Base64 encoded (with the latter, it is implicitly converted into a CipherParams object).
Possible CryptoJS implementation:


const key = "com.oneapp.manager";
const keySha256Hex = CryptoJS.SHA256(key).toString(); // create the SHA256 digest of the key material, hex encode the hash
const keyWA = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.create(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(keySha256Hex).words.slice(0, 8)); // apply the fist 8 words (= 32 bytes) of the hex encoded hash as key

const iv = "com.oneapp.consumer";
const ivSha256Hex = CryptoJS.SHA256(iv).toString(); // create the SHA256 digest of the IV material, hex encode the hash
const ivWA = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.create(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(ivSha256Hex).words.slice(0, 4)); // apply the fist 4 words (= 16 bytes) of the hex encoded hash as IV

const ciphertextB64 = 'knztSH5Icp3imQ9UQ4vdaQ=='; 
const decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(ciphertextB64, keyWA, {  // pass the ciphertext as CipherParams object or Base64 encoded
    iv: ivWA,
    padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7, // default
    mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC, // default
});

console.log(decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8)); // 1412734
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/4.2.0/crypto-js.min.js"></script>




Note that the codes have some vulnerabilities:
For the key derivation from a password, no fast digest like SHA256 should be used, but a reliable password-based key derivation (like PBKDF2, which is supported by PHP and CryptoJS).
Additionally, the key should consist of raw bytes and not ASCII encoded hex encoded bytes.
Bear in mind that reusing key/IV pairs is a more or less serious vulnerability depending on the mode.
